# Powershell Copy multiple files with certain numbers

Tags: powershell, filter, server

Still pretty new to Powershell, I would like to copy mutltiple files with from one server to an other server. The files that i want to copy contain the same two numbers 18 or 19.

```
Copy-Item -Path \\test\files\07_Export -Filter '*18.csv' -Destination \\test01\files$\2018;

Copy-Item -Path \\test\files\07_Export -Filter '*19.csv' -Destination \\test01\files$\2019;
```

As example
Test18.csv

question19.csv

searching18.csv

Right now it just copys the empty folder 07_export.

Comment: already tried that i dont know what i doesent show the * in my post here.

Answer (score 0):

This should serve your purpose.

```
$filename = (Get-ChildItem "<Source Folder>" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.FullName -imatch "18" -or $_.FullName -imatch "19" }).FullName
foreach ($file in $filename) {
    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination "<Destination Folder>"
    }
```